# Send a TextInput clicking on button without navigate

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I don't have experience in React-Native and these days I'm reading and making some simple tutorials to learn about this technology.
Today I wanted to search on how to send data from one screen to another and I have found many answers using **navigate** but I don't want to change my screen. Per example, I just want to send a simple string and when I click in my button It changes the text on the other screen.

Comment: Why send a string when you don't have to go to that screen?

Comment: @10101010 Imagine in my main screen I want to add Items to my basket and at the other screen i wanna view all of them or the total price. In my mind (and some scenarios) makes sense to send data from one screen and don't navigate to them at the same time.

Comment: It does not make sense to send data to a component that is not displayed. What makes sense is to store data for later use in a different component (using AsyncStorage, a Redux Store, the db...). But otherwise sending data would just be pointless even if possible.

Comment: @Remeus Thank you. So I'll practice just using navigate and the next step will be implementing a DB and retrieve the data for that screen. Have a nice day :)

Comment: You don't need a DB. Check https://redux.js.org/ or use AsyncStorage to briefly store informations